# Clang crosscompiling an assembler file

Tags: ios, macos, assembly, clang

I am trying to crosscompile a library for iOS on Mac OSX. I tried this with differnt libs and it worked perferkt. Now I am trying to compile an `asm` file that has some defines inside like this:

```
#if defined(__i386__)
```

and it does not work as it has the wrong defines set. I compile using this command:

```
clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk -c asm.S
```

Am I missing some flags here? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Hi, could you please explain the problem a little more?

Comment: I compile using `-arch armv7` but `__i386__` gets defined.

Comment: Have you tried `-target`?